# Android VideoView display my Video but Rotated

Tags: android, video, rotation, android-videoview

In my application I need to record a video, view the recorded video then submit it to the server.

Recording Video is working fine.. and the video saved to my android device.. 
When I go to another activity to view the video, the video displayed to me with different rotation (like if it was rotated by 90). while the video saved on my device is not rotated.

My Code:

```
captureVideoIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
captureVideoIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 30);
startActivityForResult(captureVideoIntent, VIDEO_CAPTURED);
```

onActivityResult, I saved the video Uri

```
...   mgr.videoFileUri = data.getData();  .....
```

Activity to Display the Video (with other fields):

```
video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        video.setVideoURI(mgr.videoFileUri);
        video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        video.requestFocus();
        video.start();
```

Comment: have you given rotation to VideoView in xml file???

Comment: Can you post your manifest file?